# how to execute a specific code after a ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function in which uses ajax which populate a select element of options from my database, here is the code of the function.

```
function Filtering_GetRole(roleElement) {

$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "IROA_StoredProcedures.asmx/Filtering_GetRole",
    data: "",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function (response) {

        var roletooldetails = response.d;
        var appendItem = "";

        $(roleElement).empty();

        $.each(roletooldetails, function (index, Filtering_GetRoleInfo) {

            var activeappend = "";
            var id = Filtering_GetRoleInfo.id;
            var role = Filtering_GetRoleInfo.Role;

            activeappend = "<option value=" + id + ">" + role + "</option>";


            appendItem += activeappend;

        });

        $(roleElement).prepend('<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Select Tool</option>')
        $(roleElement).append(appendItem);

    },

    error: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
        alert("error in Filtering_GetTool");
    }

});
}
```

which I call like this

```
var slcRole = $(this).closest(".td-span-buttons").closest(".tr-span-buttons").find(".slc-role"); var holdRoleId = slcRole.val();

        Filtering_GetRole(slcRole);

        slcRole.val(holdRoleId);
```

but the problem is since I use ajax the code `slcRole.val(holdRoleId);` will execute first resulting to the value not selected on the option element. How can I do that when the ajax code finished this code will execute. Sorry for the bad english

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using success and error are removed as of v3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The another way to make sure your ajax request has been processed is to use jQuery.when(), but the best way is to put slcRole.val(holdRoleId) into success callback.

Answer (score 1):

Just put `slcRole.val(holdRoleId);` into `success`.

Else, js will execute without waiting ajax done.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to execute this after `success` or `error` so instead putting in any callback or after your `Filtering_GetRole` put it in the complete callback of ajax have a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/). It will execute code within complete block when ajax  is complete. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `complete` function. `complete` executes only after the "success" of ajax. Following code will be helpful to you.

```
success: function (response) {
     // Your code
},
complete: function (response) {
   slcRole.val(holdRoleId);
},
error: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: Even if the ajax returns error then also it will execute the code written inside complete.